# Active Storage delete variants from database and recreate

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activestorage

I upgraded Active Storage to store variants record in database using

```
config.active_storage.track_variants: true
```

I duplicated some items with images and it caused broken variants
I am generating variants like

```
item.image.variant(resize_to_limit= [800, nil]).processed
```

due to these broken variants/images I want to delete variant records from database while keeping original image, and than recreate variants

how can I only remove variants?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To delete all variant records you can call

```rb
ActiveStorage::VariantRecord.delete_all
```

or

```rb
ActiveStorage::VariantRecord.destroy_all
```

To remove variants of specific item image like this

```rb
ActiveStorage::VariantRecord.where(blob_id: item.image.blob.id).delete_all
```

Comment: remove variants of specific item image was needed, thanks man

Comment: Note that `.delete_all` will **only** delete the rows from the *active_storage_variant_records* table. If you want to delete the rows in *active_storage_attachments* and *active_storage_blobs* as well, you should use `.destroy_all`.