# Re-create versions of variants in Active Storage

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activestorage

In Rails 7, I already have my `product_images` attached. But I need to create new variants from them. So I added to my `Product` model:

```
  has_many_attached :product_images do |attachable|
    attachable.variant(:thumb, resize_to_fill: [400, 400])
    attachable.variant(:medium, resize_to_fill: [800, 800])
    attachable.variant(:vertical, resize_to_fill: [500, 800])
    attachable.variant(:big, resize_to_fill: [1200, 1200])
  end
```

Now, how can I recreate the variants so the new versions get created?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Active Storage delete variants from database and recreate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74835836/active-storage-delete-variants-from-database-and-recreate)

Answer (score 0):

The dimensions/etc of the variant are used as part of it's hash/checksum, so if you change those then a new variant will automatically be created the next time it's accessed/viewed.